# Create another array every monday

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an algorithm to create a list of dates, and i need in every monday of week the code break to another array. But I don't know how to do that.

PS: Even though the monday not exists in original array, i want do create another array, for the next dates.

```js
    const mealsRooms = await prisma.users.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: req.params.userId
        },
        select: {
            MealsRooms: {
                select: {
                    id: true,
                    servingSabado: true,
                    servingDomingo: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    const monthFull = req.params.month.split(".");
    const month = monthFull[0];
    const year = monthFull[1];
    const totalDays = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), 0).getDate();
    let semana = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++){
        const data = new Date(year + "-" + (parseInt(month)+1).toString() + "-" + i);
        const indexMealZone = mealsRooms.MealsRooms.findIndex((room) => { return (room.id === req.params.zonaConsumo); })
        if(mealsRooms.MealsRooms[indexMealZone].servingSabado && data.getDay() === 6){
            semana.push({
                date: data.toDateString(),
                price: 1.46,
                status: 0,
                type: "NB",
                cosumZone: "NB"
            });
        }else if(mealsRooms.MealsRooms[indexMealZone].servingDomingo && data.getDay() === 0){
            semana.push({
                date: data.toDateString(),
                price: 1.46,
                status: 0,
                type: "NB",
                cosumZone: "NB"
            });
        }
        if(data.getDay() !== 6 && data.getDay() !== 0){
            semana.push({
                date: data.toDateString(),
                price: 1.46,
                status: 0,
                type: "NB",
                cosumZone: "NB"
            });
        }
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        listRefeicoes: [semana]
    });
```

Original Array

```js
{"listRefeicoes":[[
  {"date":"Thu Sep 01 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Fri Sep 02 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Mon Sep 05 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Tue Sep 06 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Wed Sep 07 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Thu Sep 08 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Fri Sep 09 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Mon Sep 12 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Tue Sep 13 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Wed Sep 14 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Thu Sep 15 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Fri Sep 16 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Mon Sep 19 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Tue Sep 20 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Wed Sep 21 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Thu Sep 22 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Fri Sep 23 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Mon Sep 26 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Tue Sep 27 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Wed Sep 28 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Thu Sep 29 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"},
  {"date":"Fri Sep 30 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}
]]}
```

Final Array

```js
{"listRefeicoes":[[Week 1], [Week2], ...]}
```

I tried to separate by weeks but this creates the problem that if the second one doesn't exist in the week it doesn't create the new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fold our list down into a nested list by keeping track of when our day of the week decreases.  We do that by scanning the `date` property for any of `"Mon"`, `"Tue"`, `"Wed"`, etc, keeping track of the index where that matched.  If it's smaller than our current entry, we start a new array.  If not, we append to the existing one.  Here's one way to do this:

```js
const days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

const splitWeeks = (os) => os .reduce (
  ({curr, weeks}, o) => {
    const next = days .findIndex (dow => o .date .includes (dow))
    return next < curr 
      ? {curr: 0, weeks: weeks .concat ([[o]])}
      : {curr: next, weeks: [...weeks .slice (0, -1), weeks .at (-1) .concat (o)]}
  },
  {curr: Infinity, weeks : []}
) .weeks

const update = ({listRefeicoes, ...rest}) => ({
  listRefeicoes: splitWeeks (listRefeicoes [0]),
  ...rest
})

const input = {"listRefeicoes":[[{"date":"Thu Sep 01 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Fri Sep 02 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Mon Sep 05 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Tue Sep 06 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Wed Sep 07 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Thu Sep 08 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Fri Sep 09 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Mon Sep 12 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Tue Sep 13 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Wed Sep 14 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Thu Sep 15 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Fri Sep 16 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Mon Sep 19 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Tue Sep 20 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Wed Sep 21 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Thu Sep 22 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Fri Sep 23 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Mon Sep 26 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Tue Sep 27 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Wed Sep 28 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Thu Sep 29 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}, {"date":"Fri Sep 30 2022","price":1.46,"status":0,"type":"NB","cosumZone":"NB"}]]}

console .log (update (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working. Now i will try to understand how it's made. :)

Comment: Check out [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex),  and [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for references.